# UV-place the same trim sheet evenly on several objects

Tags: uv

### TL;DR

**It's not about creating the best possible trim sheet, but about how to cleverly place a trim sheet on different objects in such a way that no transition can be seen. Almost in such a way that each UV corresponds perfectly and analogously to the placement of the previous object.**

### Details

For my project I am building a modular kit with Blender.

I have several individual pieces and would like to texture them using a trim sheet.

[image]

The problem is that (not least due to the different details like doors and windows) I’ve had trouble getting the UV mapping done accurately so that the individual pieces fit seamlessly with one another.
I wonder if there are more clever and efficient ways to unwrap the individual pieces.

Currently I select a single wall, UV-Unwrapped it and then draw the UV shape by eye so that it roughly fits. What is good practice here? Is it possible to use a kind of “snapping” or other options so that the UVs fit together despite their different shapes?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily snapping, but the UV Editor has an panel that display the UV coordinate. You can enter values to move selected UVs. That can be helpful if you know the exact position of the texture seam. It's under UV Vertex, in the Image Tab.
[image]